# Replacement option for "Visual Studio Setup (*.vdproj)" in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, windows-installer, visual-studio-2012

As per Microsoft, they have stopped the support for classic "Visual Studio Setup (*.vdproj)"  project.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/03/17/visual-studio-setup-projects-vdproj-will-not-ship-with-future-versions-of-vs.aspx

So I am searching for better option of the Replacement.

In hand : `Wix` & `InstallShield`

Suggestions please ?

Comment: "Which is better" type questions are discouraged on SO.

Comment: I re-worded to express what I beliee is the author's real intent- what are technical pro and cons of picking either options.

Answer (score 2):

What you have in hand is the answer, [Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/). Visual Studio itself uses Wix as its setup.

Comment: but it don't have UI.. we have to write the XML code :)